# How to set union shape with dynamic size and spect ratio in android drawable

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I want to make a shape like in the below image. Size in the graphic is as below

[image]

- The circle/Oval size is 30px
- The rounded rectangle height is 20px and width is 65px
- The rectangle start is set to the circle center so in total graphic size will be 80px.

[image]

> However, for drawable I need responsive size so I can use it for any
>   size of the view.

I am able to create a shape by overlapping that gives a similar illusion. I am not sure if types of boolean (graphics) is possible in android or not.

## Drawable XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="75dp"
                android:height="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:right="60dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="15dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <size
                android:width="66dp"
                android:height="20dp" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The above XML producing shape as in below screenshot

[image]

When I set the shape to `View` it output as in below screenshot

## Layout XML

```
<View
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_flask"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

## Output

[image]

As you can see, even defining size in drawable and view shape doesn't stick to the size aspect ration. I am sure it is me who is doing anything wrong.

> **Question:** How can I make the drawable shape that works on any size of view keeping aspect ration the same as it is in the **Graphic
>   reference**. And how to add Drop Shadow to it.

## EDITED

I have fixed some size issue but the shape still has a problem. For better visualization, I set different colors for both shapes.

## Drawable XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size
                android:width="80dp"
                android:height="30dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:right="60dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="15dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <size
                android:width="66dp"
                android:height="20dp" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image]

But as you can see in the below screenshot of the view it doesn't output the same size and position. However, the `View` code is the same.

[image]

Comment: Is it too difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about splitting drawables like this?

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/oval"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_oval" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rec"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/oval"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/oval"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_rec"
        android:layout_marginStart="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**shape_oval**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

**shape_rec**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <size
        android:width="66dp"
        android:height="20dp" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

> Preview

[image: Preview]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate. I can use it only if no shadow but as you can see in the graphic, I have to add drop shadow as well to element. If I will make two different shapes than the shadow will be a problem. Moreover, I can export it to SVG and can set as a background to any view but looking for drawable option.

Comment: Well, I am still waiting for a robust solution to create one single drawable. Until then I will consider your answer as working one. Thanks.